# Unir un Maestro Detalle en JSON

Tags: php, laravel, php7, laravel-6, laravel-7

Tengo un maestro y un detalle en sql, estoy obteniendo los datos de una tabla cabecera que esta esta unida  por un campo identificador a otra llamada detalle, necesito obtener los datos en JSON y lo estoy haciendo asi:

```
 $cabecera = DB::connection('sqlsrv2')
 ->select("SELECT  TOP 5 * FROM cliente 
      WHERE (pendientes= 1 )");

$datos_cabecera = [];
$detalle = [];
foreach($cabecera as $akey => $aloop) {
// leo todos los registros que tengo en la cabecera como pendientes, y busco el detalle de cada uno, en el detalle por ser porductos puede ir mas de un regitro. 
    $detalle = DB::connection('sqlsrv2')
       ->select("SELECT * FROM detalle WHERE id = $aloop->id");

         foreach($detalle as $key => $loop) {
            array_push($detalle, [
            'Codigo'=>$loop->Codigo,
            'Fecha'=>$loop->Fecha,
            ]
         }

         array_push($datos_cabecera, [
            'ID' =>$aloop->ID,
            'Fecha' =>$aloop->Fecha,
             'detalle' =>[
                    $detalle,
              ]
         ]

         //lo que quiero que me retorne es todos los maestros con su detalle en estructura JSON, si los obtengo pero no en el orden que se devería, 
         //si tengo 5 registros y cada uno con n detalles se suman los detalles al siguiente, 

         return $datos_cabecera; 
}
```

Comment: Deberías mostrar un ejemplo de cómo esperas estructurar tu Json

Comment: ¿Puedes ser mas claro en el resultado que deseas obtener por favor?